# pymongo renaming the indexed key throws duplicate key error

Tags: mongodb

Following are the documents in the mongodb. While trying to rename the indexed key, it throws the duplicate key error. I want to rename the indexed keys without any error. Please help me to achieve this

Following are the documents present in the "ne-mgmt" database and "NEs" collection.

Mongo Documents:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d15c50dbea32e000199569b"),
        "created_ts" : NumberLong("1561707789892"),
        "is_error" : "NO",
        "user_id" : "",
        "gne_port" : "34149",
        "passwd" : "",
        "target_id" : "cmbrmawa-0111105b",
        "region" : "Massachusetts",
        "ne_status" : "ASSIGNED",
}
```

Following is the error faced while renaming the indexed key
Error:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.NEs.update({}, {$rename:{"target_id":"TARGET_ID"}}, false, true);
WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 11000,
                "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: ne-mgmt-db.NEs index: target_id dup key: { : null }"
        }
})
```

Checking for indexes using the getIndexes() method. When I try to drop the index and try to rename it is working fine. But I want it without dropping the index.

Indexes:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.NEs.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "ne-mgmt-db.NEs"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "target_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "target_id",
                "ns" : "ne-mgmt-db.NEs"
        }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably creating only `unique` index on the `target_id` field.

```
db.getCollection('localdatabases').createIndex({ target_id: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

Now when running update command with `$rename` operator other fields for the same field i.e. for new `TARGET_ID` are set as `null` and thererfore it throws error for the multiple fields having the same value as `null`.

So to avoid the at situation you need to set `sparse` index as well.

```
db.getCollection('localdatabases').createIndex({ target_id: 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true })
```